# Multiply each row of a matrix with its transposed self

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

The formula I have to translate to Octave/Matlab goes something like this:

```
\sum (v_i - m) (v_i - m)^T
```

I have a matrix, and I need to take each row, subtract `m` from it and then multiply it with its own transpose. I wrote the inner part as a function:

```
function w = str(v, m)
    y = v - m
    w = y * transpose(y)
end
```

My matrix is like this

```
xx = [1 2 3 4 5; 1 2 3 4 5; 1 2 3 4 5]
```

Now I have no idea how to apply this function to each row in a matrix and then sum them up to a new matrix. Maybe someone can help me here.

EDIT: The result is **not** the dot product. I'm looking for `v * v^T`, which has a matrix as result!

Comment: If `v` is a row vector, then `v * v^T` is definitely a scalar not a matrix and it's dot product!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need this

```
X = bsxfun( @minus, A, m );
Y = X'* X;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract the mean using `bsxfun`

```
>> v_m = bsxfun( @minus, v, m );
```

For the sum of outer product of all vectors you can use `bsxfun` again

```
>> op = bsxfun( @times, permute( v, [3 1 2]), permute( v, [1 3 2] ) );
>> op = sum( op, 3 );
```

Comment: @LambdaDusk - can you be more specific? I made an edit to my answer - I hope it fits your requirements now. BTW is `m` a row vector or a scalar?

Comment: `m` is a vector, and I'm not looking for a dot product, I need to multiply each row of the matrix `A` with its **transposed** self - resulting in a set of matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the matrix is A, then the solution is

```
    total = sum(sum((A-m).*(A-m),2));
```

`A.*A` is an element wise multiplication, hence `sum(A.*A,2)` returns a column vector, with each element being the self dot product of each row in `A`.

If m is a vector then, it is slightly more complicated.

```
    [p,~]=size(A);
    total = sum(sum((A-repmat(m,p,1)).*(A-repmat(m,p,1)),2));
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I wrote this:

```
function w = str(v, m)
    y = v - m;
    w = y' * y;
end

y = zeros(5,5);
for i=1:12
    y = y + str(A(i,:), m);
end
```

Surely not the most elegant way to do this, but it seems to work.

Comment: `w = y' * y;` is not the same as `w = y * y'`. Your question and answer differ big time! You meant column when you said row ?! weird!

Comment: check my ans if you really need this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this issue:

Assume `A` is your matrix:

```
sum(drag(A' * A))
```

will do the job. However, it is slightly more efficient with the following:

```
sum((A .* A)(:))
```

Comment: The first statement was mushed by the spellchecker. It should read: sum(diag(A' * A))

Comment: Better you click on edit button below your answer instead of posting it in comments